# Client to Client remote event not working

Tags: lua, roblox

Client to Client remote event not working. I have a localscript under a button which is meant to fire a remote event when it is clicked. The remote event is then meant to be received by another localscript in starterplayerscripts which then activates sprint. The problem is, its not working and I cannot find out why.

Button script:

```
local sprintButton = script.Parent
local sprintEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("SprintEvent")

sprintButton.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    sprintEvent:FireServer()
end)
```

Starterplayerscripts script:

```
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local character
local humanoid
local isSprinting = false
local sprintDuration = 5 -- Adjust this value to set the maximum sprint duration in seconds
local sprintSpeed = 40 -- Adjust this value to set the sprinting speed
local normalSpeed = 20 -- Adjust this value to set the normal walking speed
local sprintCooldown = 10 -- Adjust this value to set the cooldown duration in seconds
local sprintTimer = 0 -- Timer to track the remaining sprint duration
local cooldownTimer = 0 -- Timer to track the cooldown

local sprintButton = Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift

player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    character = char
    humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
end)

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == sprintButton and not isSprinting and cooldownTimer <= 0 then
    StartSprint()
end
end)

UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == sprintButton and isSprinting then
        StopSprint()
    end
end)

function StartSprint()
    isSprinting = true
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = sprintSpeed
    sprintTimer = sprintDuration
    cooldownTimer = sprintCooldown
end

function StopSprint()
    isSprinting = false
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = normalSpeed
end

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if character and character.PrimaryPart and player.Character and            player.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") then
        local root = character.PrimaryPart
        local moveDirection = mouse.Hit.Position - root.Position
        local moveMagnitude = moveDirection.Magnitude

        if sprintTimer > 0 then
            sprintTimer -= RunService.RenderStepped:Wait()
        elseif isSprinting then
            StopSprint()
        end

        if cooldownTimer > 0 then
            cooldownTimer -= RunService.RenderStepped:Wait()
        end

        local speed = isSprinting and sprintSpeed or normalSpeed
        if moveMagnitude > 0 then
            humanoid:MoveTo(root.Position + moveDirection.Unit * speed)
        end
    end
end)

local sprintEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("SprintEvent")

sprintEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    if not isSprinting and cooldownTimer <= 0 then
        StartSprint()
    end
end)
```

this is the specific remote event part for the starterplayerscripts:

```
local sprintEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("SprintEvent")

sprintEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    if not isSprinting and cooldownTimer <= 0 then
        StartSprint()
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RemoteEvents](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent) are for communicating between the [client and the server](https://create.roblox.com/docs/projects/client-server), not from one LocalScript to another. If you want that behavior, you should instead use a [BindableEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BindableEvent).

BindableEvents allow you to register a callback across scripts in the same context (client-side LocalScript to another LocalScript, or server-side Script to another Script).

So convert the `SprintEvent` to a BindableEvent, then try this in your button...

```lua
local sprintButton = script.Parent
local sprintEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("SprintEvent")

sprintButton.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    sprintEvent:Fire()
end)
```

And then in the StarterPlayerScripts...

```lua
local sprintEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("SprintEvent")

sprintEvent.Event:Connect(function()
    if not isSprinting and cooldownTimer <= 0 then
        StartSprint()
    end
end)
```